# Integrating $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x^2)}{x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I found the following integral and wanted to know if there is a nice closed form solution in terms of elementary or some special functions (Polylogarithm, Clausen, etc).

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x^2)}{x^2} dx$$

I know that the integral converges numerically to $\approx 0.403926$

Here is my try using integration by parts:

Let

$$ du = \frac{\arctan(x)}{x^2} \Longrightarrow u = -\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+x^2) + \ln(x) - \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} $$

$$ v = \arctan(x^2) \Longrightarrow dv = \frac{2x}{x^4+1}$$

Hence

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x^2)}{x^2} dx \stackrel{IBP}{=} -\frac{\pi^2}{16} - \frac{1}{8}\pi \ln(2)  -2\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\ln(x)}{x^4+1} dx}_{I_{1}} + 2\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^4+1}dx}_{I_{2}} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x\ln(1+x^2)}{x^4+1}dx}_{I_{3}} $$

Can be proven that

$$I_{1} = -\frac{C}{4}$$

where $C$ is the Catalan constant and

$$I_{3} = \frac{1}{16} \pi \ln(2) $$

but I'm stuck with $I_{2}$

Another way could be:

Define

$$\Psi(a) =  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(ax)\arctan(x^2)}{x^2} dx$$

Hence

$$\Psi'(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x^2)}{x(a^2x^2+1)}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(w)}{w(a^2w+1)}dx$$

Using integration by parts, we have:

$$du = \frac{\arctan(w)}{1+a^2w} \Longrightarrow u= \frac{1}{1+a^4}\ln\left( \frac{1+a^2w}{\sqrt{1+w^2}} \right) - \frac{a^2-w}{(1+a^4)(1+a^2w)} \arctan(w)  $$

$$ v = \frac{1}{w} \Longrightarrow dv = \ln(w) $$

However, this path seems even more rugged that the other.

One last hint could be the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan(x) \arctan(x^3)}{x} dx = \frac{7}{72}\zeta(3) + \frac{\pi}{3}C - \frac{5\pi}{12}\operatorname{Cl}_{2}\left(\frac{2\pi}{3} \right)$$

where $\operatorname{Cl}_{2}$ is the Clausen function of order 2. However, I do not know the proof of this result either.

Comment: You can almost put it in terms of [Gieseking’s Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiesekingsConstant.html).

Comment: Mind sharing how you found this integral? It's quite interesting that someone posted the $I_2$ integral yesterday ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4269437/515527)) where I mentioned a closed form in the comments.

Comment: @Zacky Great, I saw your solution. I am trying to find a variation of the last integral (hint) that does not rely on the integration of polylogarithms or higher order rational functions and this integral seemed to fit well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By continuing the OP's work and using [**Cornel**'s closed-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4270694) of $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{1+x^4}\textrm{d}x$, we get that

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan(x)\arctan(x^2)}{x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
> $$=G+\frac{11}{192}\sqrt{2}\pi^2-\frac{1}{16}\log(2)\pi-\frac{3}{16}\sqrt{2}\log(\sqrt{2}-1)\pi-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_2(1-\sqrt{2})-\frac{1}{32}\psi^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right).$$

Answer (score 4):

Beside @Zacky's solution, using partial fraction, you can write
$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^4+1}=\frac i 2 \left(\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+i}-\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^2-i}\right)$$ and face two integrals
$$I(k)=\int \frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}{x^2+k}\,dx$$ which can be integrated (have a look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BArcTan%5Bx%5D%2F%28x%5E2%2Bk%29%2Cx%5D)).

The problem is that the result for the definite integral is a real monster.